# Minimizing process's memory usage

Tags: macos, safari

After upgrade to Lion OS X I've noticed new "Safari Web Content" process which is separate from the Safari.app itself. And after some time it starts using huge amounts of memory (so far, 1.2G real memory logged). Is there a way to limit process's real memory usage to, say, 500M?

Comment: Interesting. This may be related to this currently active question/discussion - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/22880/after-installing-lion-my-mac-became-super-slow/22882#22882 (safari using alot of memory)

Comment: Unused memory is wasted memory.   :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's been a couple of threads about this issue [on SuperUser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274385/how-to-limit-memory-of-a-os-x-program-ulimit-v-neither-m-are-working). I was just looking mostly for information on the ulimit command but that apparently doesn't work, it seems like there may be some solutions on that link though.